# List objects in S3 bucket with timestamp filter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

**Background**

Is there a way to get a list of all the files on a s3 bucket that are newer than a specific timestamp. For example i am trying to figure out and get a list of all the files that got modified yesterday afternoon.

In particular i have bucket called `foo-bar` and inside that i have a folder called `prod` where the files i am trying to parse through lie.

**What I am trying so far**

I referred to boto3 [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) and came up with the following so far.

```
from boto3 import client
conn = client('s3')
conn.list_objects(Bucket='foo-bar', Prefix='prod/')['Contents']
```

**Issues**

There is two issues with this solution, the first one is it is only listing 1000 files even though i have over 10,000 files and the other is i am not sure how i filter for time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter based on timestamp doing this:

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.tz import tzutc

condition_timestamp = datetime.now(tz=tzutc()) - timedelta(days=2, hours=12)  #dynamic condition
#condition_timestamp = datetime(2023, 2, 17, tzinfo=tzutc()) #Fixed condition

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
 
s3_filtered_list = [obj for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket="foo-bar",Prefix="prod/") for obj in page["Contents"] if obj['LastModified'] > condition_timestamp]

s3_filtered_list
```

Note that I give you two options to create your condition based on a timestamp... dynamic (x time from now) or fixed (x datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Since the AWS S3 API doesn't support any concept of filtering, you'll need to filter based off of the returned objects.

Further, the `list_objects` and `list_objects_v2` APIs only supports returning 1000 objects at a time, so you'll need to paginate the results, calling it again and again to get all of the objects in a bucket.  There is a helper method [`get_paginator`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html) that handles this for you.

So, you can put these two together, and get the list of all objects in a bucket, and filter them based on whatever criteria you see fit:

```python
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, UTC

# Pick a target timestamp to filter objects on or after
# Note, it must be in UTC
target_timestamp = datetime(2023, 2, 1, tzinfo=UTC)
found_objects = []

# Create and use a paginator to list more than 1000 objects in the bucket
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket=BUCKET):
    # Pull out each list of objects from each page
    for cur in page.get('Contents', []):
        # Check each object to see if it matches the target criteria
        if cur['LastModified'] >= target_timestamp:
            # If so, add it to the final list
            found_objects.append(cur)

# Just show the number of found objects in this example
print(f"Found {len(found_objects)} objects")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [S3.Paginator.ListObjects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjects), which will return `'LastModified': datetime(2015, 1, 1)` as part of object metadata in the `Contents` array.  You can then save the object `Key`s into a local list based on the `LastModified` condition.